# MacOS Sonoma to group minimized app icons like Windows

Tags: applications, dock, icon, sonoma

I come to MacOS from Windows, and I'm wondering if I can group minimized app icons just like Windows:

- in the order of when the windows was created, instead changing their icon orders every time
- group/consolidate minimized icons of the same app into one when there are too many of them, instead of occupying my dock space like this:

[image]

I presume that it most likely doesn't exist, but I think it doesn't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can group minimized icons of the same app into the application icon itself, via an option in ***System Settings —> Desktop & Dock:***

[image: System Settings —> Desktop & Dock]

You may also wish to explore the ***Stage Manager*** and ***Mission Control*** features as an alternative to minimizing windows you're not currently using.

***Stage Manager*** groups and minimizes windows within a single desktop. It's not to everyone's taste, but worth giving a try to see if you like it.

***Mission Control*** lets you arrange apps and windows among multiple desktops and easily switch between them. Using one of the ***Hot Corners*** settings to activate ***Mission Contro***l is very helpful.